# reset.css help not resetting

Tags: css, layout, reset, css-reset

I have a reset.css style sheet that looks like this,

```
    HTML * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}

body {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 83%;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
    list-style:none;
}

a,
hover,
visited {
    color:#06508b;
}

a,
img,
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}
```

Now this should make my content sit flush with the top of the browser window however it is not, can anyone see a reason for this?  You can see the problem here http://www.ibdnetwork.co.uk

Comment: Site looks fine for me in FF/Chrome/IE8. There is no margin or padding around your content.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  What browser are you using?  Perhaps a screenshot posted here will help.

Comment: Sorry wrong URL, I don't own the .com *embarrassing*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you're reset stylesheet is correctly removing the margin and padding on the body element. This leads me to think that it's something inside the body that is pushing your content out of position.

After a quick look in firebug...

It looks like your style on line 20 of default.css needs to be:

```
h1 {
    font-size:28px;
}
```

Just remove the `margin-bottom:25px`.

Comment: yep, plus i noticed some tags that aren't closed properly, like line 55: <div class="right_slider"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-257" title="scan" src="..." alt="" / </div>